# Unwrapping a non-serializable class from an appdomain

Tags: c#, reflection, appdomain

Because not all the classes used in the class I want to instantiate are serializable I can't unwrap.

Is this possible?

```
var appdom = AppDomain.CreateDomain(amServiceable.GetType().ToString());
var objectHandle = appdom.CreateInstance(amServiceable.GetType().Assembly.FullName, 
                                         amServiceable.GetType().FullName);


var plugin = objectHandle.Unwrap() as IPlugin //throws an error. that some class in not marked serializable.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the `Unwrap` method on an object it must derive from `MarshalByRefObject`.  If the object you want to manipulate doesn't then the only other choice is to use a different `MarshalByRefObject` to manipulate the object in the other domain